# How to load webpack Angular 7 module from http?

Tags: angular, typescript, webpack

I'm trying to split Angular 7.2 app into app and two module; each will be build with Webpack.
Main app will load module 1, module 2 from HTTP as children in app.routing.ts
Is there anyway to do that?

Comment: what Angular version are you using?

Comment: @Andrei: Angular 7.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I know it might not be the answer you've been looking for since you've mentioned v7. And still...

If you only update to V8 (And migrating from 7 to 8 should be really easy update) you can use the simple es import function to load any module even using the router, but also without him.

```
import(PATH_TO_MODULE).then(m => m.MODULE_NAME)
```

Comment: it seem that PATH_TO_MODULE cannot be used with module loading through Http

Comment: It will use webpack to create a chunked js from your module. When you will call the import statement it will get the chunk using http.

Comment: Thank, I understand your idea. But I need to explicit set PATH_TO_MODULE = 'http://example/module.js'

Comment: If I put chunked module js to different domaim can it be loaded as normally?

Answer (score 1):

```
RouterModule.forRoot([
    ...
    {path: 'path1', loadChildren: './module1/module1.module#Module1Module'},
    {path: 'path2', loadChildren: './module2/module2.module#Module2Module'}

])
```

with this way angular will detect lazy modules, build them separately and force them to load when appropriate path is in the url

Comment: I need to load module from HTTP; using your way module will be built directly by Webpack not loading from HTTP

Comment: it will be build by webpack and loaded by http. Am I right that you want to build modules separately (different git repositories for example)?

Comment: Yes, two modules are separately.